# jQuery select next div by class

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="fourcol "> <a class="getNote" id="1" href="#">Create a Skybox</a> </div>
<div class="fourcol "> <a class="getNote" id="2" href="#">Add images to sky box</a> </div>
<div class="fourcol last"> <a class="getNote" id="3" href="#">Delete a sky box</a> </div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="twelvecol noteDetails"></div>
</div>
<div class="fourcol "> <a class="getNote" id="4" href="#">Change a skybox</a> </div>
<div class="fourcol "> <a class="getNote" id="5" href="#">Cool a skybox</a> </div>
<div class="fourcol last"> <a class="getNote" id="6" href="#">Hey a skybox</a> </div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="twelvecol noteDetails"></div>
</div>
<div class="fourcol "> <a class="getNote" id="7" href="#">one more</a> </div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="twelvecol">
        <div class="noteDetails"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I select the first div with noteDetails class?

I have tried:

```
$('#1').closest("div.noteDetails").html('test');
```

but it doesn't work.

Edit: What I really want to do is for example if I click on the link with id 4 then I want to update the closest .noteDetails (which in this case is the second .noteDetails)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for is actually a little more difficult because of the way you have your HTML setup.  You are also missing a lot of closing tags here...

Its much easier to search for things if they are direct siblings.  Adding another class on the `.row` divs that contain the details like a `class="row rowDetails"` will make this a little easier.

This would find the next one using your current HTML though.

```
$( "a.getNote" ).click( function( event ) {
    // traverse up to the "row"
    var noteDetails = $( this ).closest(".row")
    // find the next siblings that contain a .noteDetails
            .nextAll().has( ".noteDetails" )
    // limit to the first match
            .first()
    // and then find the .noteDetails it contained
            .find(".noteDetails");
});
```

If you were to change the HTML as I suggested, you can replace the `.nextAll().has( ".noteDetails" )` with `.nextAll( ".rowDetails" )` instead.  Using a class for a selector to `nextAll()` will be much faster than having to filter with [`.has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has).

Comment: I ended up just assigning the rows ids then accessing them directly. I know the html is weird but it has to be exactly this for some ajax stuff im doing with it

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to do:

```
$("div.noteDetails").first()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div.noteDetails').filter(':first')
```

Comment: As much as this also works - [`.first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first) is actually a little speedier... Even faster [`.eq( 0 )`](http://api.jquery.com/eq) but yeah - any of these three!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div.noteDetails:first").html('test');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div .noteDetails").first();
```

Gives you the `div class="row"`

Put this somewhere to test, adding some extra class to each of the noteDetails classes to see if the right one is selected

```
document.write($("div .noteDetails").first().attr("class"));
```

This should print only the class name of your desired div and none else.

So to test, add a class `first` to the first noteDetails div and a class `second` to the next one and so on.

It should display `twelveCol noteDetails first` as the output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#1").next(".noteDetails").html("test");
```